# For things requiring multiple approvals/rejections, show current approvals/rejections

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I think my biggest frustration today whilst reviewing things is not being able to see what others reviews have contributed.

For example, currently two rejections are needed to actually reject something... but unless I'm just the only one around currently, I can't see any visual indication that someone else might have already rejected something as well. And if they have already rejected it, I'd really like to know why, because I probably want to take that into account for *my* decision.

So, at the very least, please provide a counter telling us how many more approvals/rejections are needed to actually take action, but realistically, please show us the comments others include for their rejections.

Comment: +1 I have approved something then read another's rejection comments and had a "d'oh!" moment